# Displaying list of images from SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I want to display list of images (like Google images) from a SQL Server database (byte streaming) in ASP.NET.

If it is possible using a gridview, I will feel better.

Comment: How are you storing image in the database? Is that a file path or are you streaming image by bytes into database?

Comment: storing images by bytes. im getting the problem in converting all images into gridview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to store your images in bytes to database and use it refer this link
[Image Gallery using GridView Control](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-images-from-SQL-Server-Database-in-ASP.Net-GridView-control.aspx)

for using image grid you can refer this link
[Image Gallery using ImageGrid](http://geekswithblogs.net/omtalsania7/archive/2012/12/27/how-to-create-an-image-grid-with-asp.net-44.5-using.aspx)